# Is there a way to automatically increase the app version in XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, version-control, versioning

I am looking for a automated way to increase the app version and / or build nr. Is there a way to achieve this with XCode? I am using built in git for versioning. So I actually would expect that git the version number is somehow controlled via git. At least that is how other versioning / configuration management tools work. 
I came across the possibility of using the agvtool command, but this thread [(iOS, XCode 4.2) Setting bundle version using Git post-commit hook causes my project to turn into a Mac project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731589/ios-xcode-4-2-setting-bundle-version-using-git-post-commit-hook-causes-my-pro)

made me not really using it. Is there an out-of-the-box feature for this?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number

Comment: Thanks Monolo and yes it is pretty much what I am looking for. However, I was expecting some simple options, rather than adding scripts. I am a bit concerned about the authors note "I hope this won't destabilise Xcode like the previous solution did.". Do you know if it is a stable solution and also works fine with XCode 4.2? Thanks.

Comment: I use the PlistBuddy myself in a script that reads the svn version number, and it works without any problems. Truth be told, I run the script in a secondary target that is built before the main target, if that has any influence (it could have).

Comment: Thanks Monolo, works perfectly. Have a great weekend ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of [autorevision](https://github.com/Autorevision/autorevision).

Specifically I would recommend looking at the [xcode example](https://github.com/Autorevision/autorevision/blob/master/contribs/xcode.sh), since it is explicitly setting up one header file for use in the code and another one for info.plist prepossessing. the [autorevision website](https://autorevision.github.io/Xcode/) has a walkthrough for setting this up in xcode.

Answer (score -1):

> I am looking for a automated way to increase the app version and / or
>   build nr

If it's a **text**, written somehow somewhere **inside versioned code**, Git-boys can use [smudge|clean filters](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) (read "Keyword Expansion" chapter).

I'm mad... At least I wrote about Git-filters here, at SO, already a lot of times. **When SO-search will be used** (before asking question again and again) by SO-users, especially new?!